# Static linking external library problems - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2019, static-linking

I have been trying to statically link the TagLib library to a project in Visual Studio 2019.

So far my project will build however as soon as I declare anything from the TagLib library I get an error saying: Unresolved External Symbol.

Specifically, I try creating an instance of FileRef from the file fileref.h. This causes errors:

> Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TagLib::FileName::FileName(char
> const *)" (_*imp*??0FileName@TagLib@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) referenced in
> function main
>
> 1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::FileRef(class
> TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)"
> (_*imp*??0FileRef@TagLib@@QEAA@VFileName@1@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@1@@Z)
> referenced in function main
>
> 1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl
> TagLib::FileRef::~FileRef(void)" (_*imp*??1FileRef@TagLib@@UEAA@XZ)
> referenced in function main

As far as I understand it from looking this problem up in related issues this means the linker can find the function declarations from the external library but not the definitions. I assume this is due to me linking the library incorrectly. One source I used was this: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I installed the library using cmake with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=off and ENABLE_STATIC_RUNTIME=on. For all INSTALL_DIR parameters (INCLUDE/LIB/EXEC/BIN) I used the default setting which was a folder in Program Files (x86). These were also put into their own folders (e.g. "C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include"). I had read that sometimes spaces in VS file paths can cause problems and so I attempted moving the files installed into this directory into a new directory with no spaces and linking from there. However this did not fix the error.

Once TagLib was installed, I linked it through the Visual Studio settings:

Additional Include Directories:
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\taglib\include\taglib;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Additional Library Directories:
C:\Program Files %28x86%29\taglib\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Additional Dependencies:
tag.lib

I can't seem to work out where I am going wrong with this linking and was wondering if anyone else had any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Adding include directories does not link a library. It just lets you find it's headers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5910058

Comment: Did you define `tag.lib` as a linker input file?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I also included the library in additional dependencies

Comment: @JesperJuhl That question explains the error and I understand that the error is being caused by the linker not being able to find the definitions of the functions of the external libraries. I realise this must be due to how I've linked the library. That's where I can't work out where I've gone wrong

Comment: @PaulSanders I added it as an additional dependency. Is a linker input file a separate thing?

Comment: On Visual Studio it should be Linker -> Input->Additional Dependencies

Comment: `__declspec(dllimport)` says it's expecting an import library for a DLL and not a static libraray. An import library will have a `.lib` extension. My expectation is you need to enable BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and use the dll. Unless there is some macro required to be defined to use a static library for this taglib.